# GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found

Tags: java, google-plus

I am having a problem while trying to post on my Google wall using Java API.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
Not Found
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:312)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1045)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
    at com.google.plus.samples.quickstart.domains.DomainDelegation.main(DomainDelegation.java:170)
```

Any suggestions where I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have enabled the Google+ Domains API in the developers console.

Also check out the answer in this post

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20640357/2519577